# JavaFx is not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, javafx

I'm learning some basics of JavaFx and I got to know that default java doesn't come with JavaFx. I installed it using this command `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk openjfx`, but when I try to compile my program it is still not working and giving a compilation error .

[image]

Comment: And what are the compilation error messages?

Comment: I have added it in the edits .

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen The link is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RLRP.png

Comment: Please you copy and paste into your question!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen sorry It is saying I am not allowed to embed images yet .

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Can you please look into it now ?

Comment: You need to set it up properly. I did myself a couple months ago and it wasn't that straight forward.

Comment: Check out the links in the comments on my question. Those helped me to set it up properly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354622/javafx-is-missing-in-java-openjdk